# Field 'login' doesn't exist on type Mutation

Tags: react-native, graphql, react-apollo

I am trying to make a client authentification on a React Native APP with GraphQL.

I am meeting the following error:

[image]

For me, everything is fine, I don't know why meeting this error. The form should provide the email and the password to this following gql call, no?:

```
    const GetUser = gql`
mutation login($email: String!, $password: String!) 
{
      login(email: $email, password: $password) 
}
`;
```

Here my class, I am calling the Client from App.JS, then the mutation is calling GetUser. Do you have any hint?

```
class Login extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    return {
      title: 'Se connecter',
    };
  };
 state = {
    email: '',
    password: '',
   }
   updateTextInput = (text, field) => {
    const state = this.state
    state[field] = text;
    this.setState(state);
   }
  render() {
    const { email, password } = this.state;
    return (
      
     <Mutation mutation={GetUser} onCompleted={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile')}>
       {(login, { loading, error }) => (
        <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
         <View style={styles.subContainer}>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.textInput}
            placeholder={'email'}
            value={this.state.email}
            onChangeText={(text) => this.updateTextInput(text, 'email')}
          />
         </View>
         <View style={styles.subContainer}>
          <TextInput
            style={styles.textInput}
            placeholder={'password'}
            value={this.state.password}
            onChangeText={(text) => this.updateTextInput(text, 'password')}
          />
         </View>
         
         <View>
          <Button
           large
           leftIcon={{name: 'Se connecter'}}
           title='Save'
           onPress={() => {
            login({
             variables: {
              email: this.state.email,
              password: this.state.password,
             }
            })
             .then(res => this.setState({ email: '',  password: '' }))
             .catch(err => <Text>{err}</Text>);
           }} />
         </View>
         {loading && <View style={styles.activity}>
           <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0000ff" />
          </View>}
         {error && <Text>`Error! ${error.message}`</Text>}
        </ScrollView>
       )}
      </Mutation>
    );
   }
  }
```

Warm Regards

Comment: test API - test this mutation in graphiql/playground, using variables of course

Comment: Is there in Final Schema?

Comment: This what we have to give to get a Token {login(email: "email", password: "password")}